# Execution time of a function in C (with high accuracy)

Tags: c

I'm trying to compare the execute time of searching algorithms,can anyone help me with the code,my problem is in the execute time,i use  and always is 0.00000 sec.

example of calling the binary search:

```
//BINARY SEARCH
clock_t start1,end1;
start1=clock();
binarySearch(a,size,search);
end1=clock();
extime1=(double)(end1-start1)*100000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("EXECUTION TIME FOR THE BINARY SEARCH IS %.5f SECONDS:\n\n",extime1);
```

Comment: have you tried this with large processing of data which take some time?

Comment: Run the algorithm several thousands of times, an then measure it to get somewhat feelable results.

Answer (score 0):

of course, you need some large processing of data to account for some measurable time considering the fact that computers become very fast these days.

```
int sum=2;
clock_t start1,end1;
start1=clock();
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<100;j++){
        sum+=2;
    }
}
end1=clock();
double extime1=(double)(end1-start1)*100000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("EXECUTION TIME FOR THE BINARY SEARCH IS %.5f SECONDS:\n\n",extime1);
```

> output:EXECUTION TIME FOR THE BINARY SEARCH IS 0.00000 SECONDS:

```
int sum=2;
clock_t start1,end1;
start1=clock();
for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<10000;j++){
        sum+=2;
    }
}
end1=clock();
double extime1=(double)(end1-start1)*100000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("EXECUTION TIME FOR THE BINARY SEARCH IS %.5f SECONDS:\n\n",extime1);
```

> output: EXECUTION TIME FOR THE BINARY SEARCH IS 35100.00000 SECONDS:

PS: you shouldn't multiply by 100000 as it is giving wrong unit of time.